# Crear índice de enfermedades a partir de ausencia o presencia en R

Tags: r

Me explico. Estoy trabajando con una base de datos que contiene información de enfermedades.

Variable1. Cáncer (0=Ausencia/1=Presencia)

V2. Infarto Corazón (0=Ausencia/1=Presencia)

V3. Accidente Vascular (0=Ausencia/1=Presencia)

V4. Enfermedad respiratoria crónica (0=Ausencia/1=Presencia)

V5. Cirrosis (0=Ausencia/1=Presencia)

etc.

La pregunta es cómo puedo generar una variable (índice) que clasifique la muestra según:

1. 0 Enfermedades
2. 1 Enfermedades
3. 2 o más Enfermedades

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, agrega lo que intentaste...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no pusiste un data frame, voy a crear un data frame parecido al que debes de tener.

```
set.seed(2020)
cancer<-sample(0:1, 20, T)
infarto<-sample(0:1, 20, T)
accidente<-sample(0:1, 20, T)
enf_respiratoria<-sample(0:1, 20, T)
cirrosis<-sample(0:1, 20, T)

df<-data.frame(cancer,infarto,accidente,enf_respiratoria,cirrosis)

   cancer infarto accidente enf_respiratoria cirrosis
1       1       1         1                1        1
2       1       1         1                0        0
3       0       0         1                0        1
4       1       1         0                1        0
5       1       0         1                0        1
6       0       1         1                0        0
7       0       1         1                0        1
8       1       1         0                0        0
9       1       1         1                0        1
10      1       1         0                0        1
11      0       1         0                0        0
12      0       1         0                0        1
13      1       1         1                1        1
14      1       0         1                1        0
15      1       1         1                1        1
16      1       0         0                0        1
17      1       1         1                0        1
18      1       1         0                1        1
19      1       1         1                1        0
20      0       0         0                0        0
```

Como el data frame `df` sólo contiene números puedo usar la función `rowSums()` para sumar por filas, si el resultado obtenido es `0` entonces tiene `0 enfermedades`, si la suma resulta `1` entonces  tiene `1 enfermedad`, y en casos contrarios, por ejemplo, `2 o 3 o 4 o 5` entonces que le coloque que tiene `2 o más enfermedades`.

```
df$indice<-ifelse(rowSums(df[,1:5])==0, "0 ENFERMEDADES",
           ifelse(rowSums(df[,1:5])==1, "1 ENFERMEDAD", "2 O MÁS ENFERMEDADES"))
```

Para mostrar los resultados, lo puedes ver a través de una tabla.

```
table(df$indice)

      0 ENFERMEDADES         1 ENFERMEDAD      2 O MÁS ENFERMEDADES 
            1                    1                      18
```

Si deseas tu resultado sólo en números hubieras corrido esto.

```
df$indice<-ifelse(rowSums(df[,1:5])==0, 1,
                  ifelse(rowSums(df[,1:5])==1, 2, 3))
```

Y la tabla te quedará así:

```
table(df$indice)

 1  2  3 
 1  1 18
```

Answer (score 2):

Una forma muy sencilla es usar [`cut()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut):

```
labels <- c('1. 0 Enfermedades', '2. 1 Enfermedades', '3. 2 o más Enfermedades')
cut(rowSums(df), c(-Inf,0,1,Inf), labels=labels)
```

Sumamos por fila con `rowSums()` la cantidad de enfermedades y de acuerdo al rango deseado, asignamos la etiqueta apropiada, el resultado final es un `factor`.